# PHP fetch MAX values from MySQL table for each different user

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table with many different users on my website. They upload the picture. How can I display the last uploaded picture with the highest ID number?

[image]

If I do this query:

```
SELECT user_name, MAX(pictid) FROM `pictures` GROUP BY user_name;
```

It works in PHP My Admin, but it returns empty result on the website.

[image]

Username is written correctly, just ID part is empty. Why is that? That is my code:

```
    include('connection.php'); 

$sql = "SELECT user_name, MAX(pictid) FROM `pictures` GROUP BY user_name;"; 
$result = $mysqli->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
  // output data of each row

   while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {

echo "<tr><td>". $row["user_name"] . "</td><td>". $row["pictid"] . "</td><td><img style='width:90px;' src='../uploads/".$row["picture"]."'</td><tr>";

  }
}
```

Comment: That `<img` element isn't properly closed

Comment: When selecting functions like MAX(), SUM(), COUNT() etc, MySQL will return the value with that name, so to get the result for that function, you need to call it with: `$row['MAX(pictid)']`, unless you alias it: `SELECT user_name, MAX(pictid) AS pictid FROM ...`

Comment: Thanks a lot, your answer was very helpful

Comment: I posted it as a proper answer below. If it solved the problem, please accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using functions like `MAX()`, `SUM()`, `COUNT()` etc, MySQL will return those values with a different name (so it won't collide with other column names you have in the query).

So in your case, instead of `$row["pictid"]`, it should be `$row["MAX(pictid)"]`.

However, since you're not selecting the `pictid` "as is", you can alias that function:

```
SELECT user_name, MAX(pictid) as pictid FROM `pictures` GROUP BY user_name
```

(note the `as pictid` in the query above)

Now you can fetch the value using:

```
$row['pictid']
```

### ***Side note:***

I would recommend that you [display all errors and warnings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1053424/how-do-i-get-php-errors-to-display) while developing in your local environment. In this case, you should have gotten a warning about undefined index/array key `pictid`, which would have helped you debugging the problem.

And don't forget the fix the broken `<img>` tag as [@brombeer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8034901/brombeer) pointed out in the comments to your question.